# Change Element Attribute Using XPATH / Send_Keys - Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

[image]I am writing a program to gather data from a website, however at some point in the program I need to enter an email and password into text boxes. The route I am attempting to go is to use driver.execute_script to change the underlying HTML, however I am having difficulty connecting that command with the XPATH value that I use to find the element. I know there are a few threads on here that deal with similar issues, however I have been completely unable to find one that uses XPATH. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am totally stuck here.

Below is the line of HTML that I am attempting to change, as well as the XPATH value associated with the text box.

XPATH Value

```
/html/body/center/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/font
```

HTML:

```
<input onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Name') this.value='';" onchange="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Name') this.value='';" name="name" type="text" value="Enter Your Name" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 6px; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; width:120px; height:15px; font-size:13px; color: #000000; font-family:Trebuchet MS; background:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #000000;">
```

I am attempting to replace value = "Enter Your Name" with value = "Andrew" - or any other name for that matter. Thank you very much for any and all advice, and please let me know there is any additional data / info that is required.

Send_Keys scripts:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/center/form/span/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input')
name.clear()
name.send_keys("Andrew")
```

Comment: Can you also describe how you are using `driver.execute_script`?

Comment: @budi my use of driver.execute_script is derived from another SO post. I was planning on writing something similar to driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','vote-link up voted')", element). However, if you are able to decipher why my send_keys command is not working, that would be even more helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: The `clear()` may not be necessary in your case, can you try removing this statement?

Comment: @budi yes I just removed clear() and still am having no luck. I have also tried to use name.click() to make sure the element / page is active, but it does not work with that either.

Comment: Darn, it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the actual HTML. I've added another solution using `execute_script`.

Comment: @budi Thanks, I will attempt your second solution below. Also, I know it is not SO standard protocol, but I added a screenshot of the html code to my original question. I circled the line that points to the element in red.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147971/discussion-between-budi-and-ls101).

Comment: @budi okay thank you again, I have messaged you in chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<input>` tag is contained within an `<iframe>`, so you'll need to switch the context to the `<iframe>` first:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

Now that you're "inside" the `<iframe>`, your `send_keys` script should work:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/center/form/span/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input')
name.clear()
name.send_keys("Andrew")
```

---

Lastly, here's how to switch back to the default content (out of the `<iframe>`):

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: My original attempt was to use clear() and send_keys(), however I was unable to get the program to select the box and enter the specified keys. I will edit my question to address this issue, as well as input the script I am using for this. Any help on this issue would be appreciated IMMENSELY.

Comment: I forgot to tag you in my response

Comment: Instead of adding the screenshot to my answer, please add it to your original post, thanks!